# Create a way to easily select by attributes for a complicated union file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I have polygon feature class created from a union of 3 other feature classes.   These are 5 ownership types, 3 classes of slope % and a multi-ring (3 distances; 50,75 and 100) road buffer.   So any given polygon could have 1 of 45 combinations of features; 3*5*3 =45.    I'd like to make a simple tool where a user could pick the combinations of features to quickly kick out only those areas as a mask to be used in another program.

Comment: When you say that you would "like to make a simple tool" do you mean by using ModelBuilder, ArcPy or something else?  Have you tried simply using the Select tool and training your user to use the Query Builder?

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would use the [Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) tool:

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
>   typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
>   and stores them in an output feature class.

You would just need to ensure that your users knew how to use the Query Builder.